# Removing UserControl completly from App WP8

Tags: c#, xaml, windows-phone-8, memory, user-controls

I'm having problems removing usercontrols completely from my app. Currently I'm adding the from the code behind and removing the using  the xamlObject.remove command. However when I look at the memory profiler, it does not shrink when I remove the object, but increaces when I add a new object of the same. Should I use a different command or method to remove the usercontrol completely , such that it does not stay hidden somewhere?